# Variable type name in causal inference

Tags: terminology, causality, causal-diagram

Causal inference language distinguishes different variable types: confounders, mediators, colliders, moderators.

Some time ago I encountered quite rare variable name which I can not remember. The idea of it was that only a part of the confounding variable caused outcome and variable of interest, while the other part was irrelevant. This variable, as far as I remember, had an information (caused) of this irrelevant part.

I could mess something here due to lack of memory, but I would gladly appreciate the name which could lead me to some literature describing this situation.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably thinking of a component cause, part of the sufficient component causal model. It is described briefly [here](https://sphweb.bumc.bu.edu/otlt/mph-modules/ep/ep713_causality/ep713_causality4.html).